# No lists available even with API configured and list created at mailchimp.com account

Tags: wordpress

No lists available even with API configured and list created at mailchimp.com account
What am I missing here?

1) Created account at mailchimp.com
2) Created an API key and inserted it into PMPro mailchimp

Any one help me..

Comment: refer this link ji- http://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/account-setup/create-an-account

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to  [MailChimp’shomepage](https://mailchimp.com/?_ga=1.174948450.1146948224.1492682771)  and click Sign Up Free.
2. On the Get Started page, type in your Email, Username, and Password, and click Get Started!
3. We’ll display a confirmation message. Check your inbox for the account activation email to complete your account setup.

> **Note**
>
> The time it takes to receive the activation email can vary. If you haven’t received the activation email, check your spam folder. You can also activate your account from the login page when you input your credentials and click Log In.
>
> MailChimp blocks signups from  [role-based email addresses](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/growth/limits-on-role-based-addresses) like admin@hathaway.edu or security@hathaway.edu.

**Activate Your Account**

After you receive the account activation email from MailChimp Client Services, you can complete the account setup.

1. Open the account activation email and click Activate Account.
2. On the Confirm Humanity screen, check the I’m not a robot box, and click Confirm Signup.

For more info refer this link http://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/account-setup/create-an-account

Comment: I got answer and Regenerate the API and used that API its working fine